# Peano Continua carry Convex Metrics

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, connectedness, geometric-topology, convex-geometry

I am aware of a theorem that goes as follows: If $X$ is a compact, connected metric space, then the metric on $X$ is equivalent to a convex metric if and only if $X$ is locally connected.  Here, locally connected means every point has a local basis of open, connected neighborhoods - a convex metric means a metric so that for every pair of distinct points $x, y \in X$, if $d(x,y)=2r$ there is a $z \in X$ with $d(x,z) = d(y,z) = r$.

One direction is elementary, and is given here, namely that a convex continuum is locally connected:
[Convex metric on a contiuum.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413007/convex-metric-on-a-contiuum)

The proof of the other direction was first exhibited by Moise:
https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183514376

Does anyone know if this theorem has appeared in book form before, preferably in a more modern setting?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a remark: This theorem also holds for locally compact connected metrizable spaces.